# dhtmlx scheduler applying tool-tip on y_axis

Tags: c#, javascript, tooltip, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I was wondering if it's possible to apply a tool-tip on the y_axis of my schedule.

I could not get the default tool-tip to work, which I am not sure why either, though it isn't necessary for the events. Over the names of people (y_axis), I would like to display further information such as a phone number.

It is also a timeline view.

Thanks all for your time!

Comment: Have you found a way to do it?

Comment: hello, yea I have!
I used a third party tool called [link](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) tool tipster,

It adds a tooltip to any div, after finding the necessary div, I just applied to function to it.